# Python exiting unexpectedly while closing GUI application

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to write a simple menu driven GUI program.

Following are the environment:

1. PyQt5 ver.5.10.1
2. Python 3.6.4
3. Mac OS Sierra

PyQt5 was installed using pip3.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication,
                         QWidget, QPushButton, QAction)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class myApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Some App'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 480
        self.height = 260
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.statusBar()
        pkMenuBar = self.menuBar()
        mnuFile = pkMenuBar.addMenu("File")
        mnuFile.addAction("Create New")
        mnuQuit = QAction(QIcon("ico1.png"), " Quit", self)
        mnuQuit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        mnuQuit.setStatusTip("Quit Application")
        mnuFile.addAction(mnuQuit)

        mnuFile.triggered[QAction].connect(self.triggerAct)

        self.show()

    def triggerAct(self, x):
        if x.text() == "Create New":
            print("Trigger Create New...")
        elif x.text() == " Quit":
            mnuQuit.triggered.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = myApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On executing the code (using IDLE) the GUI loads and the menu items (Actions) are also working as expected.

When the menu item "Quit" is called the app closes as well as the python icon (from the system tray). But after about 5-10 seconds I keep getting a message saying "Python quit unexpectedly".

I have been trying to figure out the problem using possible solns. by following leads on the net (like sys.exit(), app.quit() ) but every time I face the same result.

I have coding experience on ABAP/4 and VB.Net but this is very early stages for me so far as GUI coding on Python/PyQt is concerned.

Will appreciate if a lead is provided so that I may progress in this new endeavor of mine.

Thanks

Comment: It's likely because you're specifying an exit code (in `sys.exit()`).  I can't tell what `app.exec_()` returns but try pulling that out of the `exit` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really simple: `mnuQuit` is a variable not a member of the class so it can not be accessed by other methods of the class, plus I see it unnecessary to use that line of code, just call `close()`:

```
def triggerAct(self, x):
    if x.text() == "Create New":
        print("Trigger Create New...")
    elif x.text() == " Quit":
        self.close()
        # mnuQuit.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

---

It is not appropriate to call `exit()` within the GUI because the GUI has to free memory and if you call `exit()` it does not give you the time to do it. with `close()` the GUI closes correctly.

Comment: I tried that earlier but using ONLY self.close() manages to close the form but the app does not close (I can see the menu items even after the form disappears from view!!). Also Python hangs (SPOD) and I have to force quit it.

Comment: @Pradep Do you have another window open apart from myApp?

Comment: @Pradep Also do not use IDLE to test your GUI, it has limitations and are not made to handle GUI, I recommend you run it in the CMD.

Comment: Many thanks on the advice to use CMD. One clarification I got from it (reproducing below). The action call for print just worked fine. However when called " Quit", it came with the following error:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/%$^%&*#@/codes/TestMenu.py", line 56, in triggerAct
    mnuQuit.triggered.connect(self.close)
NameError: name 'mnuQuit' is not defined
Abort trap: 6

Comment: @Pradep What clarification do you want? If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that's the best way to thank

Comment: Please read my comment in its entirety. (As habit would have it I pressed return to create a paragraph to copy/paste the error from console). The error talks about "NameError: name 'mnuQuit' is not defined. Abort trap: 6.

Comment: @Pradep 
I already read it and already answered, update and you will see my comment

Comment: @Pradep As indicated in my answer, mnuQuit is a local variable whose scope is initUi(), outside of that method it does not exist, that's why this error is generated. 
you understand me?

Comment: One more thing. Any reason why IDLE would behave in this manner whereas the terminal wouldn't? Are there any work around/s?

Comment: IDLE is made to test sequential scripts, instead a GUI is executed in an event-loop. also IDLE is a very simplistic environment and at the end of the day you will not run a GUI in IDLE, I understand that you will pack it. Learn to use the terminal. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 def triggerAct(self, x):
    if x.text() == "Create New":
        print("Trigger Create New...")
    elif x.text() == " Quit":
        exit()
```

I think **exit()** will work fine in your case.